# Reading data from Flight Simulator

Tags: synchronization, hardware, simulation

I'm looking at building some hardware components to interface with Microsoft Flight Simulator which (hopefully) will display things that are currently taking up screen real estate (altimeter, airspeed indicator, radios, etc.)

Is there a way to read the values they have while FlightSim is running so that I can synchronize the external, hardware components with what they should be on screen? Preferably relatively quickly so there isn't much lag.

Comment: I assume from the promising answers below that you'll have no trouble with your original goal of integrating with MS Flight Sim, but if you do, you may want to check out FlightGear, which is an open source flight sim.  It's fairly high quality, from what I've seen.

Comment: I am considering Flight Gear as well, I haven't had a chance to try it yet (school's getting in the way) but hopefully during the summer I'll get to play with it.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: X-Plane has the ability to be interfaced too. http://www.freedomworks.ca/tag/x-plane-sdk/

Comment: Some time back I helped a gentleman with an application to send data to X-Plane. IIRC, it was very easy to send data, X-Plane had an open port you could send commands with a very simple Java socket connection. Could cause instrument failures, etc. Not sure on reading data, but likely similar.

Comment: Any similar tools for fs2020?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link may provide some insight into the MS Flight Simulator API (SimConnect ):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526983.aspx

Specifically, here is an article on Monitoring AI Objects:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974114.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Project Magenta

> With several thousand installations to date, from desk-top systems to approved flight training devices, **Project Magenta** has become a very recognizable name in flight simulation. Our products span from type-specific glass cockpits, flight management systems and interfacting software to data logging and traditional IFR training software.

- [link 1](http://www.projectmagenta.com/)
- [link 2](http://www.schiratti.com/)

This project use a interface module called FSUIPC

- [link 3](http://secure.simmarket.com/pete-dowson-fsuipc4.phtml)

  > FSUIPC4 is an add-in for Microsoft Flight Simulator X which provides an interface for other programs to read and write all sorts of pertinent data relating to the simulation, and in many ways even to control the actual process itself.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the MS SimConnect API:

http://www.fs-seine-75.com/SDK/Core%20Utilities%20Kit/SimConnect%20SDK/SimConnect.htm

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that SimConnect is a bit problematic if not only for FSX. I believe your efforts would be better directed towards one of the FSUIPC libraries which would give you interoperability with *all* Microsoft Flight Simulator versions AND Prepar3D.

Comment: On the other hand, SimConnect (FREE) offers you the capability of running from a remote PC whereas you cannot do that with FSUIPC unless you buy a license.